# Need help in understanding android memory allocator

Tags: android, memory-management

From this article, it said android has different memory allocation (e.g. pmem, cmem..) and will be switched to ion.

http://lwn.net/Articles/480055/

And I have been looking at android framework code, I think framework memory allocation is done via MemoryHeapBase class:
http://androidxref.com/4.4.2_r1/xref/frameworks/native/libs/binder/MemoryHeapBase.cpp#43

But from that class, I don't see how it allocates memory using diff memory allocation schemes.

I only see it create a shared region:

```
 int fd = ashmem_create_region(name == NULL ? "MemoryHeapBase" : name, size);
    ALOGE_IF(fd<0, "error creating ashmem region: %s", strerror(errno));
```

Can you please tell me where in the framework where it actually allocates memory using pmem? cmem? or ion?

Thank you.

Comment: As of my understanding, android maps cmem,pmem ashmem regions of available memory to the requested process and connects a file descriptor with mapped region to access the memory. See [this](http://androidxref.com/4.1.2/xref/system/core/libcutils/ashmem-dev.c#42)

Answer (score 0):

ashmem is used to share memory b/w processes just by passing file descriptor.

First you will create ashmem regoin, then you will use that fd to mmap in process space.

If this process wants to share mmaped file then it will just pass fd to another process through binder.

Answer (score 0):

as far as I know, the MemoryHeapBase, IMemoryHeap and IMemory relates to the ashmem model for shared memory operations in Binder RPC.

Memory allocation is done by ION in HAL layer. Then fd is passed to MemoryHeapBase for share.

Ps：
You could refer to android/hardware/vendor/camera/... code